# Nothing happens when event is executed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an confusing problem.

Code as below, I cannot see anything wrong, I've compared with my other code and it is in exactly the same/very similar format but this one doesn't execute the event for some reason.

I've also tried doing this in the if statements:

```
if (regExName.test(theForm.txtName.value))
```

Still the same error, nothing happens at all. The lbl??? display no message at all to whether or not it's working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 265px;
        }
        #Text1 {
            width: 186px;
        }
        #Text2 {
            width: 186px;
        }
        #Text3 {
            width: 186px;
        }
        #txtName {
            width: 186px;
        }
        #txtAge {
            width: 186px;
        }
        #txtNumber {
            width: 186px;
        }
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function btnValidate(theForm) {
            regExName = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]");
            regExAge = new RegExp("^([1])?[0-9]{2}");
            regExNum = new RegExp("[2-9][0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}");

            if (regExName.test(theForm.txtName))
                lblName.innerHTML = "Valid, continue.";
            else 
                lblName.innerHTML = "Invalid Name Entry, please try again.";

            if (regExAge.test(theForm.txtAge))
                lblAge.innerHTML = "Valid, continue.";
            else
                lblAge.innerHTML = "Invalid Age Entry, please try again.";

            if (regExNum.test(theForm.txtNumber))
                lblNumber.innerHTML = "Valid, continue.";
            else
                lblNumber.innerHTML = "Invalid Phone Number Entry, please try again.";
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">

    <table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input id="txtName" type="text" /></td>
            <td>
                <div id="lblName">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">Age:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input id="txtAge" type="text" /></td>
            <td>
                <div id="lblAge">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">Number:
                <input id="txtNumber" type="text" /></td>
            <td>
                <div id="lblNumber">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Validate" onsubmit="btnValidate(this.form)"/></p>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED CODE**

Comment: you do not have a form?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: `this.form` doesn't seem to exist.  Thats why you can't access its properties in the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button isn't in a form, so `this.form` returns `undefined`. Put the a form around the outside of the table (and button), and put the validation listener on the form's `onsubmit` handler, not on the button. And change the input type button to an input type submit.

Some other suggestions regarding the code:

```
>   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

The language attribute for script elements was deprecated in HTML 4 and is removed in HTML5, just don't use it. The type attribute is optional in HTML5 (and has been in practice for a very long time) so consider removing it too. One less opportunity for error.

```
>   function btnValidate(theForm) {
>        regExName = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]");
>        regExAge = new RegExp("^([1])?[0-9]{2}");
>        regExNum = new RegExp("[2-9][0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}");
```

Variables should be kept local using the `var` keyword, so:

```
        var regExName = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]");
        var regExAge = new RegExp("^([1])?[0-9]{2}");
        var regExNum = new RegExp("[2-9][0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}");
```

.

```
>        if (regExName.test(theForm.txtName))
>            lblName.innerHTML = "Valid, continue.";
```

Don't use element id's as global variables, it is a design flaw introduced in early IE and mimicked by other browsers for compatability, just don't do it. Get a reference to the element using:

```
         var lblName = document.getElementById('lblName');
```

.

```
>        else 
>            lblName.innerHTML = "Invalid Name Entry, please try again.";
```

Please use brackets around if statements. It makes the code more readable and easier to maintain. The above can be applied to the rest of the code too.

As for the HTML:

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

You have an HTML DOCTYPE, so remove the xmlns attribute.

Form controls must be in a form and have a name to be sucessful (i.e. for their value to be sent to the server when the form is submitted). So replace the control ID with a name, e.g.

```
<input name="txtName" type="text">
```

Lastly, don't use XML style markup in an HTML document.

#### Edit

So here is your code cleaned up. Note that the function must return `false` to cancel submit, otherwise the form will submit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <title></title>
  <script>

    function btnValidate(theForm) {
      var regExName = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]");
      var regExAge = new RegExp("^([1])?[0-9]{2}");
      var regExNum = new RegExp("[2-9][0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}");
      var lblName = document.getElementById('lblName');
      var lblAge = document.getElementById('lblAge');
      var lblNumber = document.getElementById('lblNumber');
      var returnValue = true;

      if (regExName.test(theForm.txtName.value)) {
         lblName.innerHTML = "Valid, continue."

      // If test fails, write error message and set returnValue to false
      } else {
         lblName.innerHTML = "Invalid Name Entry, please try again.";
         returnValue = false;
      }

      if (regExAge.test(theForm.txtAge.value)) {
         lblAge.innerHTML = "Valid, continue.";
      } else {
         lblAge.innerHTML = "Invalid Age Entry, please try again.";
         returnValue = false;
      }

      if (regExNum.test(theForm.txtNumber.value)) {
         lblNumber.innerHTML = "Valid, continue.";
      } else {
         lblNumber.innerHTML = "Invalid Phone Number Entry, please try again.";
         returnValue = false;
      }

      // returnValue will be either false, cancelling submit, or 
      // any other value to continue submit 
      return returnValue;
    }

  </script>

  <!-- note that the listener must return a value -->
  <form action=""  onsubmit="return btnValidate(this)">

    <table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input name="txtName" type="text"></td>
            <td>
                <div id="lblName"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">Age:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input name="txtAge" type="text"></td>
            <td>
                <div id="lblAge">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">Number:
                <input name="txtNumber" type="text" /></td>
            <td>
                <div id="lblNumber">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Validate"></p>
  </form>
</html>
```

Comment: This is one of the many problems with this approach.  I would strongly recommend trying a standard validation technique like jQuery validate: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Comment: I've done as you've said and now my textbox values just disappears and there is no message displayed telling me it works. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Milimetric—jQuery won't fix the OPs code or markup issues, nor will it teach anything about javascript.

Comment: @RobG Thank you, that fixed pretty much everything and helped me learn what I was missing. However, I have one last request of you. Is it possible to keep the values as displayed when typed in to demonstrate to my fellow student and assist him? (I'm tutoring a student so I'm just catching up.) What I mean is when I hit the button and everything is valid, the page just resets everything, the text in the textboxes, and the validation messages.

Comment: @RionMurphMurphy—You can have the function always return false, then the form won't submit. If you want the form to keep its values after being submitted, better to have the server include them in the response or submit the form using AJAX and don't actually submit the form.

Comment: Well spoken! I am set to go now. Again, thank you very much for your help in my adventures!